# Can someone show how to reduce the general integral of $\vec{A}$ to the one used by the author in the first line?

Tags: electromagnetism, dirac-delta-distributions

Example 10.2 of 3rd edition Griffith [electrodynamics]
[click here to read this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyMJr.png)

So I thought to convert I into $\vec{J}$ as follows :
$$\vec{J}(\vec{r},t)= I_o\theta(t)\delta(x)\delta(y)\hat{z}$$
Here $\theta(t)$ is [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) and $\delta(x)$ is just a [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).
And now we know that as $\rho$ is assumed as zero. So $\phi=0$, and now we know that the formula for vector potential is $$\vec{A}(\vec{r},t)=\dfrac{\mu_o}{4\pi}\int\int\int\frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r'},t_{retarded})}{\mathfrak{r}}d\tau'$$
If we take the above integral and solve then it doesn't reduce to this:-
$$\vec{A}=\dfrac{\mu_o}{4\pi}\hat{z}\int{\frac{I}{\mathfrak{r}}dz}$$
as claimed by the author in the first step.
[click this to read the solution of the author](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW2Jh.png)
. A small note for those might be familiar with electrodynamics. By 'I' I mean the electric current defined as $$I(t)\equiv\dfrac{d}{dt}q(t)$$ and here $$\vec{r}\equiv<x,y,z>$$  is position vector of any point in some given frame. Here $$\vec{r'}\equiv<x',y',z'>$$ be the position vector of the source charges and source currents. And let $$\vec{\mathfrak{r}}\equiv\vec{r}-\vec{r'}$$ be oistion vector defined with respect to the source point. And here $t_{retarted}\equiv t-\frac{\mathfrak{r}}{c}$. And $d\tau=dV=d^3\textbf{r}$ [volume element][ which can become $dxdydz$ in Cartesian system, and $sdsd\phi dz$ in cylindrical system which should be used due to cylindrical symmetry]

Comment: Are you sure your expression for $J$ is correct? The time dependence is all right, but do you not think that in your expression for $J$ the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$ are singled out? Which cannot be the case from the symmetry of the problem.

Comment: I am fairly confident the integrand should be in terms of the magnitude of $\mathbf{r}$, not the vector form, such that you find the Green's function for the result.  Given that this is greatly simplified by the presence of the delta functions, it should be straight forward to solve, should it not?  By the way, to what does $\tau'$ refer?

Comment: @GattuMytraya. I think $\vec{J}$ is correct if we assume the wire to be aligned along z-axis. This is my justification for that $\rightarrow$ $$\int\int_{S} \vec{J}\cdot d\vec{A}=I_o\theta(t)$$ where 'S' is some surface over which we are integrating and it contains origin. And if 'S' doesn't contain origin, then the integral will be zero. Or if 'S' contains origin 2 times but in opposite sense[ I mean the area element] then again I will become zero instead of $I_o\theta(t)$